# No query defined for that name [findStreet]

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following entity Street.java:

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(
                name = "findStreet",
                query = "select s from Street s"
        )
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "STREET", schema = "C##HOUSE")
public class Street implements java.io.Serializable {
    ...
}
```

JUnit Test Case

```
@Test
public void test03(){
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findStreet");
    List<Street> list = query.getResultList();
}
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name [findStreet]
```

Comment: verify that its configuration is `@EntityScan("com.server.models")`

Comment: I don't use Spring

Comment: Is that class loaded? i.e is it in persistence-unit `<class>` ? look in the JPA provider log